# Bash vs Perl/Python: OS call perfomace

Tags: python, bash, perl, unix

Two scripts:

Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while (1) {
   my $cmd = "echo bla | grep bla";
   system($cmd);
}
```

Bash

```
while true;
do echo bla | grep bla;
done;
```

I'm getting a rather significant(about 10% on a single core) difference in CPU utilization. Any thoughts?

Here's what I'm trying to troubleshoot: We have some legacy scripts written in Bash that run every X seconds. Upon inspection, we noticed that they consume a significant share of resources. After rewriting those scripts to Perl/Python the CPU utilization went down significantly.

The Bash scripts heavily use calling external programs(awk,cut,grep,sed,etc.), while Perl/Python scripts were self-contained. I would attribute it to the fact that Bash forks/execs whenever it needs to create an external call, thus we are spending time creating thousands of processes.

Comment: How are you running that bash script? Is `system` running `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Both are running `bash`.

Comment: Documentation for `system` seems to indicate that it uses `/bin/sh -c` for execution. That isn't `bash` (at least not in normal bash mode and will use different initialization files, etc.). But as to the real issue yes, it seems likely that a shell script heavily relying on external programs will run slower than a custom-written perl script that uses built-in functionality.

Comment: Gotcha. I figured it has to be something like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Etan Reisner, but `/bin/sh` is often `bash`.

Comment: @ikegami-Not necessarily,it ca be any of the `POSIX satisfying sh`! You can't conclude about it without accessing the system...

Comment: Even if it is `bash` the binary it will not be run in normal bash mode which will change initialization files if nothing else (and it may very well change some internal state such that performance characteristics change).

Comment: In which way does the performance change? The Perl version probably loops faster - JIT compiled code, while the bash's command execution is faster - `echo` is a built-in, only a grep process is spawned every iteration. With perl, a shell is spawned each iteration and that spawns a grep process.. Overall, with this, I expect the bash version to be faster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example, the Perl CPU utilization is less, because it only loop and invoke a shell (to run `system`)

The bash script does both the looping and echo.

A fairer comparison would use the following shell script: (to force a subshell for the echo)

```
while true; do 
  ( echo bla | grep bla; )
done;
```

Or even: (To keep it from simply forking)

```
while true; do 
  sh -c 'echo bla | grep bla'
done;
```

In that case, I expect Perl to perform better (lower CPU usage), since it uses [a partial optimizing "compiler"](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlcompile.html). For the example, the main process mainly spend its time waiting for the subprocess(es) to return.

With the current one, the higher bash usage can be partially attributed to the bash script doing more (`echo` is a built-in command, Perl starts a shell with the entire command, which in turn runs echo and start a grep process) - The Perl process has lower CPU usage, but overall the usage is likely more.

A more equivalent Perl script would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while (1) {
   open(CMD,"|-","grep","bla");
   print CMD "bla\n";
   close(CMD);
}
```

Of course, comparing the performance is likely also relevant:

10 second iterations (counted with `wc -l`, killing bash / perl process after a 10 second sleep with `pkill`) on the same system:

- The Perl version above: 6190
- Your bash version: 6146
- Subshell bash version: 4267
- Bash with `sh -c`: 2584
- Your Perl version: 2389

So: Perl is slightly (if at all significant) faster, CPU usage is a bit lower (about half), but that is likely due to a better parser than bash.